# how to create a fit HStack with equal space between it's object

Tags: swift, swiftui, hstack

I wanna create an HStack with levitating space between objects, but equal between each one and also it must fit on horizontal, Some of like that

[image]

[image]

I used Spacer() between objects, like that

```
HStack {
            Text("Object1")
            Spacer()
            Text("Object2")
            Spacer()
            Text("ASASASA")
            Spacer()
            Text("asa")
       }
       .padding()
```

But there is just a question, Is there any way better than for making my code cleaner??

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this? You might want to set the `alignment:` to what you need.

```
HStack(spacing: 20) {
    Group {
        Text("Object1")
        Text("Object2")
        Text("ASASASA")
        Text("asa")
    }
    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
}
```

Comment: I wanna have a levitating space between object, but There is a fix 20 pixel space between objects

Comment: You might rephrase your original question. You first talk about  a "equal space between object" then about a "levitating space between object"

Comment: try this article https://alejandromp.com/blog/2019/06/13/implementing-a-equally-spaced-stack-in-swiftui-thanks-to-tupleview/